# Can I test to see if a player has placed a bed without creating a scoreboard objective?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can I test to see if a player placed a bed without setting up a dummy scoreboard objective to keep track of it?

I am trying to pack only what I need into the size of a single structure block. Once the group has failed the mini game it is necessary to place the game in a new world, so all I need do is place the structure in the new world and start the game place the structure and open the world to multiplayer. Hence the less overhead the better.

Comment: I honestly don't know if you can do this with a scoreboard objective off the top of my head. You definitely can't do it without. Why do you specifically need without?

Comment: You can track it "without setting up a **dummy** scoreboard", but not without creating any scoreboard objectives at all. I'd echo Unionhawk and ask if it's really necessary to not use a scoreboard objective.

Comment: Not sure if I understand why this got downvoted.

Comment: Why can't you use scoreboards? If it's because you don't know how, someone can put a good explanation in their answer.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that there is no reason not to set up a scoreboard. The only way you could find out without setting up a scoreboard is by following them.